# Embedded ActiveMQ: jdbcPersistenceAdapter using kahaDB?

Tags: persistence, activemq-classic

I've the following Spring config of the ActiveMQ Broker:

```
<broker:broker id="activemqbroker" useJmx="false" persistent="true" brokerName="activemqbroker">
    <broker:transportConnectors>
        <broker:transportConnector name="vm" uri="vm://activemqbroker"/>
    </broker:transportConnectors>
    <broker:persistenceAdapter>
        <broker:jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataSource="#oracle-ds" transactionIsolation="2">
            <broker:statements>
                <broker:statements tablePrefix="IAG_PROC_"/>
            </broker:statements>
        </broker:jdbcPersistenceAdapter>
    </broker:persistenceAdapter>
</broker:broker>
```

And the problem is that the active-mq directory with KahaDB is still being created and used. I don't understand why because I'm not using *journaledJDBC* but *jdbcPersistenceAdapter*. How could I setup this to use only JDBC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scheduler feature in ActiveMQ uses its own KahaDB persistent store, try setting it to disabled on the broker element via: schedulerSupport=false.

Comment: Ok, the file now it's not created but I still see the following trace. Do you know what's happening? 2012.12.13 13:56:52 - WARN  - main - org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService                       - Store limit is 102400 mb, whilst the data directory: /home/carga/process/camel only has 3342 mb of usable space

Comment: Depends a bit on your broker version, there were some things fixed in this area in the 5.8-SNAPSHOTs.  Also without you full config file its hard to guess.

Comment: I've found an open issue regarding this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-4031 thanks Tim