# Does ActiveMQ always require the KahaDB library, even when using JDBC persistence?

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm trying to set up the following broker using JDBC persistence:

```
<amq:broker id="activeMQBroker" brokerName="activeMQBroker" useJmx="false" persistent="true">
    <amq:transportConnectors>
        <amq:transportConnector name="vm" uri="vm://activeMQBroker" />
    </amq:transportConnectors>
    <amq:persistenceAdapter>
        <amq:jdbcPersistenceAdapter dataSource="#dataSource" />
    </amq:persistenceAdapter>
</amq:broker>
```

On startup, I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/kahadb/page/Transaction$Closure
```

If I add the KahaDB JAR to the classpath, all is well and the ActiveMQ database tables get created (in Postgres).  I'd rather not have this additional dependency, though, since I'm not using it.

Any idea why ActiveMQ is still looking for KahaDB, even though I'm using JDBC?  I tried setting `schedulerSupport="false"`, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13857373/612265), but no luck.

P.S.  Could someone with enough rep please create a "KahaDB" tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current versions of ActiveMQ are ***tied***  pretty hard to KahaDB.  The TempStore uses a paged list that uses KahaDB underneath as well.  Its simplest to just include the library.